# How to show game center authenticate login alert multi times?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm building a game and I want to make game center something like the app High Moon. Which is when authenticating, when Apple's game center login alert shows, if the user tap cancel, I will show an alert, when my alert dismisses, I want to show Apple's game center login again. This means if the user doesn't login to game center, he can't play the game. 
   The problem is that,when I call authenticate method to show the login alert again, Apple's game center login alert doesn't show. Someone know how to show it again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't.

And the interesting part in this, if the user presses cancel three times in a row, the dialog won't appear again. Ever. Even if you have the authentication code called, the user has to go to the game center app, login, then come back.

Source: GameKit Docs.

Comment: Thanks. I know if the user presses cancel three times, it won't appear, the only way to login after this is to login from game center app. I think there must be a way to do what I want, because the app High Moon is doing so.